# Retrieving JSON Input Values in laravel not working

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-7

Im using **Laravel 7.*** and i want to post data as `JSON` to laravel route.

Due to the [Laravel documantation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#retrieving-input) JSON fileds must be accessible using this code :

```
$name = $request->input('user.name');
```

this is a pieces of laravel documentation :

> When sending JSON requests to your application, you may access the
>   JSON data via the input method as long as the Content-Type header of
>   the request is properly set to application/json.

I'm testing it by **RestMan** extension in browser and i'm sending data with `content-type:application/json` Header .

But the `$request->input()` is empty always.

I tested `$request->json();` and this method is working fine . why `input()` method NOT works for retrive json data ?

**Edit  :**

this is my request in RestMan : 
[image]

And this is my Route :

```
    Route::post('/get-json-data',function(Request $request){
    return $request->input('user.name');
});
```

Comment: You should show the request. Does RestMan Export the request to Curl? Could help us to know more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `user` parameter in the request is an array of jsons, so you'd need to specify the index to access individual names

```
$request->input('user.0.name');
$request->input('user.1.name');
```

or loop through it and get an array of names like this

```
$names = [];
foreach($request->user as $user){
    $names[] = $user->name;
}
```

Your original code

```
$request->input('user.name');
```

checks would work if `user` was a json field and `name` is a field in the json, something like

```
{
    "user":{
        "name":"Ford"
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem was my understanding of JSON . thanks . problem solved